# Advantage of including sub flows in SWF flow design

Tags: spring-webflow

I can design SWF with or with out sub flows. Can anybody explain what are the advantages of designing flows in subflow manner in SWF. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main advantage is for modularity of flows (If you are reusing flows), SRP princinple, and to be able to return control back to a "main" flow that's driving a larger transaction.

This is best explained with an example. Say you are running a Vacation booking website designed with SWF.

Say you have the flow definitions:

**consistents of main flow and (3) subflows below**

```
"book-vacation-flow.xml"
```

**individual flows that can be referenced as subflows**

```
"book-plane-tickets-flow.xml"  (stand alone flow )
"book-hotel-flow.xml"          (stand alone flow )
"book-car-rental-flow.xml"     (stand alone flow )
```

You have individual flows that represent specific products/transactions a user can purchase (i.e plane tickets, hotel, car rental) but you also have a use case where a user wants combine those transactions/flows into a single "flow" (i.e book-vacation) that could potentially use all 3 flows.

So the book-vacation-flow.xml has its own flow.xml definition that drives the "book vacation transaction" but inside of it you define the ( 3 ) flows book-plane-tickets-flow.xml, book-hotel-flow.xml, book-car-rental-flow.xml as subflow definitions.

The advantage of this setup lets you"reuse" each individual standalone flow as both a standalone flow and a subflow.

As stated earlier the benefits of this is separation of concerns (SRP principle) and for reuse-ability of flows.

**Also couple of other notes:**

- A really nice features of main flow <-> subflow is the passing of
  full pojos between the two without having to bind or use http params.
- subflows don't have to be standalone flows they can be "private" to
  the main caller flow but in my personal opinion it is not worth using
  subflows in such use cases. It just leads to confusion. Only use a
  subflow if you plan to reuse that subflow functionality in other main
  flows.